# Spring boot and Jpa Related clarification

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Suppose i have a spring-boot application that has starter-JPA dependencies.
I need to know if spring checks the connection to the db at the startup?

For example, if i have mentioned a Database that i do not have access to (like below), will the application fail to start? If yes what would be the exception?

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the last version of Spring Boot 2.7.2, Spring Boot doesn't check a connection itself, but gets a connection to determine some properties. Also Hibernate needs a connection to determine some properties itself (controlled by `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults`).

Also if you have `spring-boot-starter-actuator` as a dependency, a connection will be checked at the startup (controlled by `management.health.db.enabled`).

It needs to specify all automatically determined properties explicitly to not  get a connection during the startup (even `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddlAuto`)

Add this to `application.yaml`

```yaml
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddlAuto: "none"
spring.datasource.driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false #Hibernate

# disable datasource check on startup
management.health.db.enabled: false #spring-boot-starter-actuator
```

By default Hikari is used as a connection pool. The connection pool gets all connections at the first attempt to get a connection. That's why it doesn't get the connections during the startup.

Comment: @ladynev I had the same thought , but then how Spring gonna have session-factory (pool of connections) bean at the start? (considering i am using hibernate the default implementation). I might be asking a lot, can you please explain logic behind it?

Comment: @mautilaregistan I was mistaken. The last time I checked this behavior, it was for the oldest Spring Boot versions. You can change `spring.datasource.url` to something incorrect and check the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing much. Just execute your query. If the connection has died, either your JDBC driver will reconnect (if it supports it, and you enabled it in your connection string--most don't support it) or else you'll get an exception.

our best chance is to just perform a simple query against one table, e.g.:

```
select 1 from SOME_TABLE;
```

Comment: This query is usually performed by connection pool.